# ElectronJS and compile for Windows CE 6.0

Tags: node.js, electron, windows-mobile-6

I make quick electronjs app from this tutorial: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/quick-start

Now I want to compile app for `Windows Mobile CE 6.0`. In package.json I have:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "build": "electron-packager . --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"TestApp\""
  },
```

While run `npm run build` I have error:

> C:\my-electron-app>npm run build
>
> > my-electron-app@1.0.0 build
> > electron-packager . --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName="TestApp"
>
> WARNING: --asar does not take any arguments, it only has
> sub-properties (see --help) EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir
> 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\electron-packager\win32-ia32\AppName-win32-ia32-BFIGvY\resources\app\node_modules\at-least-node'

`...\AppName-win32-ia32-BFIGvY\resources\app\node_modules\at-least-node` folder is empty.

Where is problem and how resolve them?